Does English have example of oa / о "alteration"?
I know that oa goes back to OE o / a: foal > fola, board >bord or boat > bat, road > rad 
I know the example of oa / a "alteration" roam but ramble
Does English have example of oa / о "alteration"?

It's not very clear what you want. Do you want two words from the same Old English or Proto-Germanic root, one spelt "oa" and the other "o"? Loaf and lord have a common root, and poach is related to poke.

@StuartF two words from the same Old English o, one spelt "oa" and the other "o"

The Development of oa Spellings in Early Modern English
Albert H. Marckwardt
American Speech
Vol. 52, No. 1/2 (Spring - Summer, 1977), pp. 105-111 (7 pages)
Published By: Duke University Press

Yes, English has such an example: road / rode.
